KMM project iOS: Unresolved reference: cocoapods
I work on a KMM application. Android app works very well on Macbook Pro with M3 and iOS worked well until now. Recently it started showing error like pod install failed with error code 1.  pod install was ok from terminal in ios directory  
After deleting the project and clone again, Android is compile and run without any problems but in iOS in Xcode 15.4 i get the following errors on some kotlin code that lives in iosMain directory 
Unresolved reference: cocoapods
In other mac book's it works very well, and also it works until yesterday in this same machine.  


can you share your kmm project's build.gradle.kts, need to verify if required cocoapods have been added there in dependencies.
Also do check this, your problem might be the same

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/79021976/556617

Upgrade your Kotlin version to 2.1.0-Beta1.
The link between Xcode and Kotlin broke a bit ago, and they've just now patched it.
